# Can someone please suggest me to create dynamic xpath for https://jpetstore.cfapps.io/catalog/categories/FISH

Tags: selenium

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Testing\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://jpetstore.cfapps.io/login");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Testing");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("test@123");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'FISH')]/img")).click();
```

> **Here I was able to create dynamic xpath**
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Catalog']//parent::td//preceding-sibling::td//a//following::td//a")).click();
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Catalog']//parent::a//following::a[contains(text(),'Add to Cart')]")).click();
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='BackLink']//a[contains(text(),'Return to Main Menu')]")).click();
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='SidebarContent']//a[@href='/catalog/categories/FISH']")).click();

Comment: **Credentials is invalid**

Comment: Testing2780/test@123

Comment: I feel you are able to click on the element with text as **FISH** i.e. the element with `contains(@href,'FISH')`. Are you looking for something else? What exactly do you mean by **dynamic xpath**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to click on that link then you need to take the xpath till `a` node, try the below xpath :

```
String xPath = "//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'FISH')]";
```

If you are still getting an exception then you need to give some delay before clicking on it :

```
 Thread.sleep(3000);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'FISH')]")).click();
```

You can use FluentWait to avoid some exceptions, try the below code if you want to use the FluentWait :

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, StaleElementReferenceException.class);
WebElement fish = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'FISH')]"));
    }
});
fish.click();
```

**Update :**

As per the discussion in the comments, here is the solution :

```
driver.get("https://jpetstore.cfapps.io/login");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("some username");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("some password");
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'FISH')]")).click();
// Replace Name('Angelfish') with any fish you want
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Angelfish']/preceding-sibling::td/a")).click();

// Replace Description('Small') with any size you want
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[text()='Small']/parent::td/following::td//a[@class='Button'])[1]")).click();
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: i tried to create dynamic xpath but unable to do .login into https://jpetstore.cfapps.io/catalog;UN/pwd:Testing/test@123;click on fish label;i want xpath of product ID of angelfish.

Comment: @Testing Passion, your question is not clear. Use the above locator, it is clicking on the Fish. What do you mean my `angelfish`?

Comment: After clicking on fish image,page is navigating to another page.In that page i want to perform click .so im using "//div[@id='Catalog']//parent::a[contains(@href,'FI-SW-01')]".After clicking on that link ,page is navigating to add to cart page.In this page im unable to find unique xpath for add to cart button.If you can find unique xpath for add to cart button.Then my problem will be solved.

Comment: I have added the updated code, check and let me know it is working or not? If its helpful then please do accept and up vote my answer. Thank you...

Comment: How to get xpath of description of added product to cart .large angelfish both are in same table but in different span

Comment: Have you executed the answer that I have provided? You just need to replace the text there... It's not that much complicated, observe the xpath and substitute the correct input...